# cd into an application

Tags: bash, osx-snow-leopard

Mystery solved...

```
[nemo@Saturn.local /Applications/AppsUser/System]$ ls -l | grep ExpanDrive
-rw-r--r--@  1 nemo  admin         0 Nov 16  2010 ExpanDrive.app
[nemo@Saturn.local /Applications/AppsUser/System]$ file ExpanDrive.app 
ExpanDrive.app: empty
```

Works fine for other apps. Now what, do I delete this question seeing as how it's invalid?

---

I'm trying to get a little binary inside an application bundle to run from the commandline, like

```
$ ./ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/expan
```

('expan' is the binary inside ExpanDrive's application bundle)

This doesn't work, ("Not a directory"), nor can I cd into it, or list its contents. Are there toggles for `cd` and `ls` that allow this, or other utilities?

To clarify, this is what happens:

```
[nemo@Saturn.local /Applications/AppsUser/System]$ cd ExpanDrive.app 
-bash: cd: ExpanDrive.app: Not a directory
[nemo@Saturn.local /Applications/AppsUser/System]$ ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/expan
-bash: ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/expan: Not a directory
```

Is it possible that this does not work because I'm logged in over SSH?

Comment: what is expan?? file or folder?

Comment: expan is the name of the binary I'm trying to run, inside ExpanDrive's application bundle. It's just an example though.

Comment: use only `ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/expan`

Comment: Hrm. Good one, I found it does work on Mountain Lion (with or without a leading "./"), but not on Leopard Snow. I'm SSH'd in if that makes a difference (I hope not!).

Comment: From the `/Applications/AppsUser/System` directory, will you `ls -l | grep ExpanDrive` and tell us the output? Also, `file ExpanDrive.app`.

Comment: @WilliamJackson: mystery solved! `file ExpanDrive.app` says it's "empty". So.. yeah, I could cd into other apps fine, somehow that Application got messed up.. had not thought to try different things first >.<

Comment: I closed the question as too localized since no one else will be able to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually just specify the full path:

```
/Applications/ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/expan
```

This would also work:

```
cd /Applications/
ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/expan
```

`./` is only needed for running executables in the current folder.

```
cd /Applications/ExpanDrive.app/Contents/Resources/
./expan
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that last tidbit. However this does not work for me :-/ updated question.